# How do I set the backup destination directory of bup?

Tags: configuration, backup

[bup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/bup) defaults to saving backups to `~/.bup`. How can I tell it to save backups to my external drive (`/media/backups`) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [bup's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/bup.1.html):

```
GLOBAL OPTIONS

    [...]

    -d, --bup-dir=BUP_DIR
          use  the given BUP_DIR parameter as the bup repository location,
          instead of reading it from the $BUP_DIR environment variable  or
          using the default ~/.bup location.
```

So either start it with the `-d` switch or set the `$BUP_DIR` variable.

Comment: Thanks. I'd been looking in the manuals for [bup-index](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/bup-index.1.html) and [bup-save](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/bup-save.1.html) — the commands I'm actually using — and neither one mentions `--bup-dir`, `$BUP_DIR`, or the existence of global options.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to symlink .bup there:

```
ln -s /media/backups ~/.bup
```